# Scons build order

Tags: python, scons

We have two tools: Tool1 and Tool2. Tool1 create some TargetFile, based on the SourceFile. Now we want to use TargetFile int the Tool2 to create another NewTargetFile. Structure is similar to this:

```
   env.Tool1(TargetFile, SourceFile)
   env.Tool2(NewTargetFile, TargetFile)
```

Emitter of the Tool2 is using TargetFile to do some magis. As result, Scons says that it can't open TargetFile (because it wasn't builded yet).

How to make so, that Scons will build Tool1 before Tool2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the return value of the first call (a Node or a list of Nodes) as input to the second call:

```
res = env.Tool1(TargetFile, SourceFile)
env.Tool2(NewTargetFile, res)
```

This should create the required dependency automatically. Usually, specifying a simple filename as string, like "foo.in", for `TargetFile` should work too. But I'm guessing that your Emitter is doing tricks and returning additional filenames, or a completely different filename than `TargetFile` instead. You may want to check the return value with:

```
res = env.Tool1(TargetFile, SourceFile)
print map(str, res)
env.Tool2(NewTargetFile, res)
```

, or similar.

Comment: How is it possible a structure, if Tool2 use TargetFile (or res) to create new targets for build?

Comment: I don't understand this question, sorry. You might want to open a new topic/question where you explain the things in more detail.